# How does an NFA use epsilon transitions?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

In the picture below, I'm trying to figure out what exactly this NFA is accepting.

[image]

What's confusing me is the $\epsilon$ jump at $q_0$.

- If a $0$ is entered, does the system move to both $q_0$ **and** $q_1$ (the accept state)?
- If a $1$ is entered, does the system move to both $q_1$ and $q_2$?
- Does the system only move to $q_1$ (accept state), if *no input* is given (empty string)?

Comment: Go back to the definitions: an NFA accepts a word if *any* computation on it accepts. NFAs are not, per se, "algorithms" in the sense DFA are.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every time you are in a state which has a $\epsilon$ transition, it means you automatically are in BOTH states, to simplify this to you:

If the string is $\epsilon$ then your automata ends both in $q_0$ and $q_1$

If your string is '0' it'll be again in $q_0$ and $q_1$

If your string is '1', it'll be only in $q_2$, because if you look from the point of $q_0$, you have a '1' transition to $q_2$, but you have also to look at case you're in $q_1$(if you were in $q_0$ you always were in $q_1$ also) then there is no '1' transition, so this alternative path just "dies".

Just by looking at these cases its easy to see that your automata accepts $\epsilon$, $0^*$, and going from $q_0$ to $q_1$, the only way to reach $q_2$ is $0^*11^*1$, so, this resumes your automata to $\epsilon$, $0^*$, $0^*11^*1$

Hope this helped you, if you have any further doubts, just ask!

Comment: "it means you automatically are in BOTH states" -- I don't think that that is a helpful intuition, i.e. it represents non-determinism in a wrong way.

Comment: Why does it represent it wrong? Well, by the definition of delta on non-determinism, you get a set of state instead of only 1 correctly? This can means only that you are in both states.

Comment: It promotes the idea that non-deterministic machines "try all solutions in parallel". That is not what happens, algorithmically speaking. Nondeterminism is a descriptive formalism, not an algorithmic technique.

Comment: I tried to put it in an understandable way since hes struggling to understand the principles of nondeterminism in a theoric way

Comment: @Raphael What would be a more helpful intuition, in your opinion?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy It's about whether an acception computation *exists*. If you need an "executionist" intuition, the one where "the automaton always guesses right" comes closest.

Comment: There is no such thing as guessing right. Guessing right is exploring all possibilities and accepting those that works. One way to avoid this parallelism thought is computing a new DFA for the joint states preserving the branchings and removing all empty transitions. Think deeper at what guessing right is...

Comment: @Raphael This question is about interpreting diagrams of automata, so by intuition in this case I mean an intuitive way of interpreting $\varepsilon$-move arrows. Splitting/parallel execution seems like a decent intuitive framework for this purpose. What do you mean by "the automaton always guesses right"?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy The acceptance criterion is "there is a path ...". By "picking" this (not necessarily unique) path, the "automaton always guesses correctly". Of course, there is no guessing; existential acceptance criteria  do not provide operational semantics.

Comment: Does the automata also have a choice of _not consuming_ the character, yet taking the epsilon transition? Or the semantics of epsilon transition is just that we will consider where all we _can_ be before having consumed any character?

Answer (score 6):

In state $q_0$ without reading any input the NFA both stays in $q_0$ and (in an alternative universe, if you will) it also moves to state $q_1$. This is similar to what would happen in an NFA which had two transitions to different states on an input of a character. In particular, your NFA accepts the empty string, since on no input it can make a transition to the accept state $q_1$.

Continuing your example, from state $q_0$ seeing input $0$, it would consume that symbol, stay in state $q_0$ (the loop) and also go to state $q_1$, thereby accepting input $0$. In state $q_0$ reading input $1$, the NFA would go to state $q_2$. It might also not consume the $1$, change to state $q_1$ in another universe and get stuck there (and not accept, since it hadn't read all the input), since there's no transition from $q_1$ on a $1$.

See if you can convince yourself that the language accepted by this machine is denoted by the regular expression $0^*+0^*11^*1$, i.e., any string consisting of zero or more $0$s followed by either nothing at all or two or more $1$s.

---

By the way, there's an algorithm which takes an NFA with $\epsilon$-moves and produces an equivalent NFA without $\epsilon$-moves, which I expect you'll learn shortly.

Comment: "Continuing your example, from state q0 seeing input 0, it would consume that symbol, stay in state q0 (the loop), and also go to state q1, thereby accepting input 0". Does the automaton also have the freedom to not at all consume the character and just keep keep taking epsilon moves? This would be a problem wherein, any string that is _not valid_ as a part of the alphabet is also accepted right?

Answer (score -1):

I tried construct DFA for this  NFA

$\sum$ - alphabet set

$Q$ -states set

$\sigma(Q\times (\sum  \cup {\epsilon} )) \to P(Q)$ state func

$q_0 = q_0$

$ F \subseteq Q, F = \{q_0\}$

Because every NFA has equal DFA  lets construct
DFA $M'$ for this given NFA.

alphabet  - the same

$Q' = P(Q)$  - states

Current state is $R \in P(Q)$

$E(R)$ - epsilon closure return set of states reachable over zero or more $\epsilon$ - connections for every $r \in R$

$\sigma'(R,a) = \bigcup_{r \in R} E(\sigma(r,a)) $ -transitions

$q'_{0} = E(\{q_0\})$

$F' = P(Q) \div F$

Some compute on this FSM

$1.$ $\epsilon$ on input:  $q'_{0} = E(\{q0\}) = \{q_0, q_1\}$ initial state include $q_1$ so FSM accept $\epsilon$

$2.$ $0*$ on input: $ \sigma'(\{q_0, q_1\}, 0) = E(\sigma(q_0,0)) \cup E(\sigma(q_1,0)) =
\{q_0, q_1\} \cup \{ \} = \{q_0, q_1\}$
so FSM accept $0*$

at least $\{\epsilon, 0*  \} \subset L (M')$

Thanks to [David Richerby](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/9550/david-richerby)

Comment: Thanks for thanking me but I don't really see how this answers the question. You haven't established what language the machine accepts and you haven't addressed any of the three bulletted questions.

Comment: 1) when input is $\epsilon$ (empty string) , FSM state is  $\{q_0, q_1\}$ 2) when input  is $0$  or even $0*$  FSM state is  $\{q_0, q_1\}$  both of those subjects of  initial questions, is not it?